# NVIDIA Nsight Debugging on GTX 480

Tags: cuda, gpu, nsight

I have one machine with GeForce GTX 480 but I can't debug or run analysis activity on it.
This error appears when I debug or run analysis activity:

> The remote system is logged in through Remote Desktop. CUDA debugging
>   does not support Remote Desktop unless a TCC adapter is installed.

My Nsight version is 2.2. Whats wrong?

Comment: It is a pretty self explanatory error. What don't you understand?

Comment: @talonmies : deat talonmies how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a TCC capable card (Quadro or Tesla series) if you want to use the GPU from inside a RPD session.

When you do not have a TCC capable GPU, you can for example install VNC Server as a service and use that to access the machine.

Alternatively you can configure windows autologin to log you in automatically and have have the Nsight Monitor in the startup group (but to access the desktop remotely you would still need some kind of remote access software like VNC).

Comment: VNC is a great solution . thank you again my friend for your help

Comment: @farzad: The requirement for a Quadro or Tesla card for using TCC is an artificial limitation imposed by NVIDIA. It is possible to edit the BIOS on you card to work around it. See [unlocking TCC-mode on GeForce](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/489965/cuda-programming-and-performance/gtx480-to-c2050-hack-or-unlocking-tcc-mode-on-geforce/).

Answer (score 0):

after some test and try ,I found that this problem is because of RDC and if you  connect to the target machine from one computer with remote desktop connection even if you disconnect all remote desktop and try to debug with Nsight remotely or locally you get this error .

I  were connected to the target machine with remote desktop and configure and run Nsight monitor and then close the RDC . and then I tried to  debug the project remotely from host on the target and because of it I get this error

I found that one solution will be restart the target machine and configure the Monitor physically at front of the target machine and then DO NOT remote to the target from anywhere, now I can debug my project from host machine on the target machine .